# Parsing an array of nested objects in Javascript using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

I want to print all the brand names with their parent name by traversing through this array. For top level brands , parent as "None".
e.g. `None : Parle, Parle : Parle Agro, Parle Agro : Frooti`

```
let inventory = [
  {
    brand: 'Parle',
    products: [
      {
        brand: 'Parle Agro',
        products: [
          {
            brand: 'Frooti',
            products: []
          },
          {
            brand: 'Bailey',
            products: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: 'Pepsico',
    products: [
      {
        brand: 'VB',
        products: [
          {
            brand: 'Lays',
            products: []
          },
          {
            brand: 'Kurkure',
            products: [
              {
                brand: 'Mad Angles',
                products: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        brand: 'Pepsi',
        products: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: 'Cadbury',
    products: []
  } 
];
```

I have tried following approach but I'm missing out somewhere.

```
function brandName(obj){
for (var key in obj) {
    var item = obj[key];
    if (typeof item === "object"){
        brandName(item.products); }
} } brandName(inventory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I've used a recursion that gets an inventory and a parent (default None) and prints the parent along with all the children. Then doing recursion for each of the children, having the child itself as parent. It's easier to see the code.

```js
var inventory = [{brand:"Parle",products:[{brand:"Parle Agro",products:[{brand:"Frooti",products:[]},{brand:"Bailey",products:[]}]}]},{brand:"Pepsico",products:[{brand:"VB",products:[{brand:"Lays",products:[]},{brand:"Kurkure",products:[{brand:"Mad Angles",products:[]}]}]},{brand:"Pepsi",products:[]}]},{brand:"Cadbury",products:[]}]

function brandName(inventory, parent) {
  parent = parent || "None"
  inventory.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(parent + " : " + item.brand)
    brandName(item.products, item.brand)
  })
}

brandName(inventory);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I see you keep using `var` in your answers which isn't recommended now that there are more specifically scoped `let` and `const` (in this case even changing the OP's `let` to a `var`). Also you are redeclaring the parameter here instead of simply assigning it a default value in the function declaration plus you're using an OR short circuit which is better replaced with nullish coallescing.

Comment: `var`  - being a more general form of `let`, `const` or any future keyword - is enough for me. Function fixed. Short circuiting is fun.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive generator that allows the caller to decide the effect. `menu` does a simple type analysis on the input `t` and responds accordingly -

```js
function *menu(t, parent = "None") {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      for (const child of t)
        yield *menu(child, parent)
      break
    case Object:
      yield [parent, t.brand]
      yield *menu(t.products, t.brand)
      break
  }
}

const inventory =
  [{brand:"Parle",products:[{brand:"Parle Agro",products:[{brand:"Frooti",products:[]},{brand:"Bailey",products:[]}]}]},{brand:"Pepsico",products:[{brand:"VB",products:[{brand:"Lays",products:[]},{brand:"Kurkure",products:[{brand:"Mad Angles",products:[]}]}]},{brand:"Pepsi",products:[]}]},{brand:"Cadbury",products:[]}]

for (const item of menu(inventory))
  console.log(item.join(":"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
None:Parle
Parle:Parle Agro
Parle Agro:Frooti
Parle Agro:Bailey
None:Pepsico
Pepsico:VB
VB:Lays
VB:Kurkure
Kurkure:Mad Angles
Pepsico:Pepsi
None:Cadbury
```

If you want to collect all of the items in an array, use `Array.from` -

```js
Array.from(menu(inventory))
// => [ ["None", "Parle"], ["Parle", "Parle Agro"], ...]
```

```js
Array.from(menu(inventory), p => p.join(":"))
// [ "None:Pare", "Parle:Parle Agro", ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursion will extract all the brand/parent pairs into an array of objects:

```js
const collectBrands = (xs, parent = "None") =>
  xs .flatMap (({brand, products = []}) => [
    {brand, parent},
    ... collectBrands (products, brand)
  ])

const inventory = [{brand: "Parle", products: [{brand: "Parle Agro", products: [{brand: "Frooti", products: []}, {brand: "Bailey", products: []}]}]}, {brand: "Pepsico", products: [{brand: "VB", products: [{brand: "Lays", products: []}, {brand: "Kurkure", products: [{brand: "Mad Angles", products: []}]}]}, {brand: "Pepsi", products: []}]}, {brand: "Cadbury", products: []}]

console .log (collectBrands (inventory))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply `map` over the input, extracting the current `brand` and `parent` into an object (defaulting `parent` to `'None'`), recurring on the list of `products`, and combining them into a single list.  By using `flatMap` we combined these into a single list of results.

That will yield something like this:

```js
[
  {brand: "Parle", parent: "None"},
  {brand: "Parle Agro", parent: "Parle"}, 
  {brand: "Frooti", parent: "Parle Agro"}, 
  {brand: "Bailey", parent: "Parle Agro"},
  {brand: "Pepsico", parent: "None"},
  {brand: "VB", parent: "Pepsico"},
  {brand: "Lays", parent: "VB"},
  {brand: "Kurkure", parent: "VB"},
  {brand: "Mad Angles", parent: "Kurkure"},
  {brand: "Pepsi", parent: "Pepsico"},
  {brand: "Cadbury", parent: "None"}
]
```

And if you want them all in your String format, you can create this array and then format it with something like this:
:

```js
console .log (
  collectBrands (inventory) .map (({parent, brand}) => `${parent}: ${brand}`) .join (', ')
) 
//=> "None: Parle, Parle: Parle Agro, Parle Agro: Frooti, Parle Agro: Bailey, None: Pepsico, Pepsico: VB, VB: Lays, VB: Kurkure, Kurkure: Mad Angles, Pepsico: Pepsi, None: Cadbury"
```